# Accessing a BLOB field with SQLAlchemy and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, blob

I am writing my first larger application with SQLAlchemy ORM using SQLite as a database engine.
I have a one-to-many relationship between tables Item and Attachments. The relevant code is:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    __table_args__ = ({'keep_existing': True})

    item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    description = Column(types.Text, nullable=False)

    # ... other attributes skipped
    # one-to-many bidirectional relationship to Attachments
    attachments = relationship('Attachment', backref='item')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Item(%s)" % self.title


class Attachment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'attachments'
    __table_args__ = ({'keep_existing': True})

    attachment_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.item_id'))
    name = Column(String(255))
    filetype = Column(String(32))
    description = Column(String(255))
    data_blobb = deferred(Column(types.LargeBinary))
    modification_date = Column(types.DateTime, nullable=False,
                               server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Attachment(%s.%s: %s)" % (self.name, self.filetype, self.description)
```

The problem appears when I try to execute the following simple query:

```
session_factory = orm.sessionmaker(bind=dbengine)
sc_session = orm.scoped_session(session_factory)
session = sc_session()

query = session.query(Item)

for res in query.limit(10):
    print res.item_id, ' --> ', res.authors, ' --> ', res.categories, ' --> ', res.attachments
```

When the program wants to print res.attachments, it yields a SELECT statement including the BLOB column and crashes with the well-known

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xda' in position 267: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When executing the same SELECT in a bare sqlite3-based Python script, I can avoid the exception by calling `.encode('utf-8')` on the returned content.

I also tried [coercing](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#coercing-encoded-strings-to-unicode) the retrieved content, but with no success.
What should I do in order to be able to access the said column with SQLAlchemy?